# Is it possible to dynamically add useState hooks in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project where the user can create 'things' which I then associate state with.

A simple version of how I am doing this is basically:

```
function App() {
   const [things, setThings] = useState({})
}
```

Unfortunately things ends up being a fairly large and heavily nested (at least a few layers deep anyways) object.

something like this:

```
{
  things: [
      {
         field1: 'value1',
         field2: {...}
         ...
      },
      ...
   ],
   otherThings: ...
}
```

I know it is not ideal to store so much in one hook, especially since different parts of it will be basically being constantly updated.

So my question is basically:
Is there some way where I can dynamically add different useState hooks, so that my state management looks more like:

```
   const [thing1, setThing1] = useState({...})
   const [thing2, setThing1] = useState({...})
   const [otherthing1, setOtherthing1] = useState({...})
```

With different useState hooks being added or removed based on user actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks cannot be [conditional and should only be called at the top level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). React recommends using multiple states and [grouping states](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) that change together.  If your state is truly really large (being nested doesn't make it large, total size does) you can use browser storages like [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to prevent the browser from using too many resources and crashing.